# Where can i find the documentation for webpack 3?

Tags: webpack

I can't find any documentation for the webpack 3.

Currently I'm using webpack 4 and I wanted to use the `extract-text-webpack-plugin` which is not supported in webpack 4, so I wanted to downgrade to webpack 3 since the `extract-text-webpack-plugin` is supported up to that version.

Is there any way I can get the documentation of webpack v3?

Comment: It looks like the main documentation is kind of jQuery-esue, where they lump all the versions together and then call out version differences where they exist. That said, it doesn't look like it's consistent about pointing out differences.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can download the v.3.11.0 [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack.js.org/archive/v3.11.0.zip)

It is from the old Docs and Guides from Webpacks GitHub Repo.

https://github.com/webpack/webpack.js.org/releases/tag/v3.11.0

Navigate to `src > content > guides`

All `.md` files. Hope I could help you out :)

EDIT: Community hosted: https://webpack-v3.netlify.com/ (not mine)

Comment: If anyone wonders. There is [webpack v3.11](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/v3.11.0) and [webpack.js.org v3.11](https://github.com/webpack/webpack.js.org/tree/v3.11.0) - the docs website. Two separate repos. So if you search for v3.12 docs (or think the docs are part of the source) you're out of luck.

Answer (score 4):

As this issue is still unresolved, I tried fetching site snapshots from https://web.archive.org and found my version at

https://web.archive.org/web/20180216190554/https://webpack.js.org/concepts/

Though bit slow but worth trying.

Answer (score 4):

As [mentioned](https://github.com/webpack/webpack.js.org/issues/1854) on the issue tracker of webpack, GitHub user [bendtherules](https://github.com/bendtherules) was so nice to host the webpack v3 doc on an extra website: https://webpack-v3.jsx.app/

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is only one set of documentation and the webpack team aims to indicate in the documentation when there are differences between version 3 and 4.

Edit 4/2019: copies of the V3 doc have been set up [here](https://webpack-v3.jsx.app/) and [here](https://webpack-3.cdn.bcebos.com/) now by members of the community. The individual .md files can be found [in this folder (and its subfolders) on github](https://github.com/webpack/webpack.js.org/tree/v3.11.0/src/content).

Edit 4/2020: Now the site carries the webpack 5 beta documentation. [V4 documentation is here](https://v4.webpack.js.org/).

Comment: The URL https://webpack.js.org/v3 does not exist. The referenced webpack issue is asking for them to change to versioned documentation, and suggests the v3 URL as a way to do that. It is not saying that documentation currently exists at that URL.

Comment: That said, @JDB is correct in his comment above. The webpack documentation is not versioned; according to the same webpack issue referenced here by Catweazle, the docs for v3 should be very similar to the docs for v4. You should be able to rely on the current documentation for v3.

Comment: There were significant changes to the plugin API for version 4. Having version 3 docs easily accessible is a must for enterprises that still rely on it and haven't upgraded. The second link seems to work (https://webpack-3.cdn.bcebos.com/). Not sure why this got downvoted either.